# Spring Security dynamic access depending on user's id

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible in Spring Security to dynamically restrict access of different users to different data depending on their id?

For example, I want user 1 to be able to query /users/get/1 to get their record from the database, but not be able to query /users/get/2 to get user #2's record.

**Edit:**

Let me explain why I'm worried about this. User 1 could change his password by requesting /user/change_password/1 using his access token, but he can also change user 2's password.
Even considering that to change the password to a new one, you need to enter the current one, I believe that this is a security hole, since the current password can be found out by brute force.